# unreachable statement switch

Tags: java

I have a POS program that is not working it says ***switch(food)*** unreachable statement

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class sari{
public static void One()
{
int choice=0,food=0,c=0,con,x=1,y=1,z=1,q=1,trans=0,price=0 ,qty,gtotal=0,ptotal=0,pay,change,total=0,ord;
String order="",bibilhin="",transaction="",A;




                   ImageIcon welcome = new ImageIcon("welcome.jpg");
            ImageIcon chip = new ImageIcon("chip.jpg");
            ImageIcon rc = new ImageIcon("rc.jpg");
            ImageIcon stick = new ImageIcon("stick.jpg");
            ImageIcon pancit = new ImageIcon("pancit.jpg");
            ImageIcon jampong = new ImageIcon("jampong.jpg");
            ImageIcon chups = new ImageIcon("chups.jpg");
            ImageIcon egg = new ImageIcon("egg.jpg");
            A=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name:");              ImageIcon hansel = new ImageIcon("hansel.jpg");

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sir/Ma`am \n "+A+"\n Welcome\n to Mang Inasal\n Please Choose The\n product you want to buy","Welcome" ,JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,welcome);
    while(x==1) 
            {
            c=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("  Categories" + "\n" +"[1] Drinks" + "\n" + "[2] Foods"));



    if(c==1)
        {choice=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("DRINKS" +"\n"
                        + "[1] Lemonade" + "\n"
                        + "[2] Coca Cola" + "\n"
                        + "[3] Sprite" + "\n"
                        + "[4] Mountain Dew" + "\n"
                        + "[5] Pepsi" + "\n"
                        + "[6] Cofee" +"\n"
                        + "[7] Hot Choco" +  "\n"
                        + "[8] Nestie Iced Tea" +"\n"
                        + "[9] Exit" +"\n"
                        + "Enter Your Choice:"));
    if(c==2)
        food=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Food" +"\n"
                        + "[1] L" + "\n"
                        + "[2] Coca Cola" + "\n"
                        + "[3] Sprite" + "\n"
                        + "[4] Mountain Dew" + "\n"
                        + "[5] Pepsi" + "\n"
                        + "[6] Cofee" +"\n"
                        + "[7] Hot Choco" +  "\n"
                        + "[8] Nestie Iced Tea" +"\n"
                        + "[9] Exit" +"\n"
                        + "Enter Your Choice:"));   

    }

        switch(choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    price = 20;
                    bibilhin= " Lemonade";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    price = 20;
                    bibilhin= "Coca Cola ";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    price =820;
                    bibilhin = "Sprite";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    price =205;
                    bibilhin= "Mountain dew";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    price =20;
                    bibilhin= "Pepsi";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    price =25;
                    bibilhin= "Cofee ";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    price =25;
                    bibilhin= "Hot Choco";
                    break;
                case 8:
                    price = 20;
                    bibilhin= "Nestie Ice tea";
                    break;
                case 9:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,transaction+"Total sales: " + gtotal,"Transactions",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You are about to exit!","Exit",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    do{
                        con=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Are you sure you want to exit?\n[1] Yes\n[0] No"));
                        if(con==1)
                            System.exit(0);
                        else if(con==1)
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"THANK YOU!\nGood Bye!","Exit",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                            break;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Choice!","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                            con=1;
                        }

                       }while(con==1);
                       continue;
                default:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Choice!","ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}

            do{//do1

            qty = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Quantity:"));

            if (qty>0)
                break;
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Input!","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                continue;
            }
            }while(q==1);//end do1

            total = price * qty;
            ptotal = ptotal+total;
            order = order +bibilhin+"                 "+qty+"                  "+price+"="+total+"\n";

            do  {//do2
            con = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Continue?[1] yes [0] no"));
                    if(con==1)
                    {

                        break;
                    }
                    else if(con==0)
                    {

                        do{
pay = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(order+"Total " +ptotal+"\nEnter Payment:"));
if(pay>=ptotal)
                                {

change = pay-ptotal;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"  \t                    Mang Inasal"+
            "\n\t           14 T molina st purok 6-B "+
            "\n\t              Alabang Muntinlupa City  "+
            "\nOperator: Micko Mendoza"+
            "\n\t----------------------------------------------------------------"+
            "\n\n\t   "+order+"\nTotal "+ptotal+
"\nCash "+pay+
"\nChange "+change+
            "\n----------------------------------------------------------------"+
            "\n\n \t            Thanks For buying!!!!!"+
                            "\n\t  This Serve as an official reciept DTSN:41D983"+
            "\n     \t       For Delivery Dial (519-6936)"+
            "\n    \t               Feedbacks"+
            "\n  \t             micko.mendoza@yahoo.com"
);
                                    y=0;
                                    z=0;
                                    x=1;
                                    gtotal = gtotal+ptotal;
                                    trans++;
                                    order="";
                                    transaction = transaction+"Transaction "+ trans+ " "+ptotal+"\n";//No of transactions
                                    ptotal = 0;
                                    do{
                                        con=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Next Customer?\n[1] Yes\n[0] No"));
                                        if(con==1)
                                            break;
                                        else if(con==0)
                                        {
                                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,transaction+"Total sales: " + gtotal,"Transactions",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                                            System.exit(0);
                                        }
                    else
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Choice!","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        continue;
                    }

                }while(con==1);
                                    break;
                                }
                            else
                                {
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Kulang pera mo");

                                    continue;
                                }
                            }while(z==1);//do3

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Intiger lang pwede","Continue",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        y=1;
                        continue;
                    }
                }   while(y==1);//do2

                break;




        switch(food)
            {
                case 11:
                    price = 20;
                    bibilhin= " Lemonade";
                    break;
                case 12:
                    price = 20;
                    bibilhin= "Coca Cola ";
                    break;
                case 13:
                    price =820;
                    bibilhin = "Sprite";
                    break;
                case 14:
                    price =205;
                    bibilhin= "Mountain dew";
                    break;
                case 15:
                    price =20;
                    bibilhin= "Pepsi";
                    break;
                case 16:
                    price =25;
                    bibilhin= "Cofee ";
                    break;
                case 17:
                    price =25;
                    bibilhin= "Hot Choco";
                    break;
                case 18:
                    price = 20;
                    bibilhin= "Nestie Ice tea";
                    break;
                case 19:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,transaction+"Total sales: " + gtotal,"Transactions",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You are about to exit!","Exit",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    do{
                        con=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Are you sure you want to exit?\n[1] Yes\n[0] No"));
                        if(con==1)
                            System.exit(0);
                        else if(con==1)
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"THANK YOU!\nGood Bye!","Exit",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                            break;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Choice!","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                            con=1;
                        }

                       }while(con==1);
                       continue;
                default:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Choice!","ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}

            do{//do1

            qty = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Quantity:"));

            if (qty>0)
                break;
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Input!","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                continue;
            }
            }while(q==1);//end do1

            total = price * qty;
            ptotal = ptotal+total;
            order = order +bibilhin+"                 "+qty+"                  "+price+"="+total+"\n";

            do  {//do2
            con = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Continue?[1] yes [0] no"));
                    if(con==1)
                    {

                        break;
                    }
                    else if(con==0)
                    {

                        do{
pay = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(order+"Total " +ptotal+"\nEnter Payment:"));
if(pay>=ptotal)
                                {

change = pay-ptotal;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"  \t                    Mang Inasal"+
                "\n\t           14 T molina st purok 6-B "+
            "\n\t              Alabang Muntinlupa City  "+
            "\nOperator: Micko Mendoza"+
            "\n\t----------------------------------------------------------------"+
            "\n\n\t   "+order+"\nTotal "+ptotal+
"\nCash "+pay+
"\nChange "+change+
            "\n----------------------------------------------------------------"+
            "\n\n \t            Thanks For buying!!!!!"+
                            "\n\t  This Serve as an official reciept DTSN:41D983"+
            "\n     \t       For Delivery Dial (519-6936)"+
            "\n    \t               Feedbacks"+
            "\n  \t             micko.mendoza@yahoo.com"
    );
                                    y=0;
                                    z=0;
                                    x=1;
                                    gtotal = gtotal+ptotal;
                                    trans++;
                                    order="";
                                    transaction = transaction+"Transaction "+ trans+ " "+ptotal+"\n";//No of transactions
                                    ptotal = 0;
                                    do{
                                        con=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Next Customer?\n[1] Yes\n[0] No"));
                                        if(con==1)
                                            break;
                                        else if(con==0)
                                        {
                                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,transaction+"Total sales: " + gtotal,"Transactions",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                                            System.exit(0);
                                        }
                    else
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Choice!","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        continue;
                    }

                }while(con==1);
                                    break;
                                }
                            else
                                {
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Kulang pera mo");

                                    continue;
                                }
                            }while(z==1);//do3

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Intiger lang pwede","Continue",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        y=1;
                        continue;
                    }
                }   while(y==1);//do2




                continue;



}   
}
}
```

Comment: It's because you have a `break` sentence before it, so no matter what happens, the code after this `break` will never be executed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have an unconditional `break` right before the `switch` in question.

As an aside, I think this is the perfect time to learn about functions and how to use them to make code more modular.

Answer (score 0):

comment the break statement

import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;

```
public class Test{
public static void main(String[] args) 

{
int choice=0,food=0,c=0,con,x=1,y=1,z=1,q=1,trans=0,price=0 ,qty,gtotal=0,ptotal=0,pay,change,total=0,ord;
String order="",bibilhin="",transaction="",A;




                   ImageIcon welcome = new ImageIcon("welcome.jpg");
            ImageIcon chip = new ImageIcon("chip.jpg");
            ImageIcon rc = new ImageIcon("rc.jpg");
            ImageIcon stick = new ImageIcon("stick.jpg");
            ImageIcon pancit = new ImageIcon("pancit.jpg");
            ImageIcon jampong = new ImageIcon("jampong.jpg");
            ImageIcon chups = new ImageIcon("chups.jpg");
            ImageIcon egg = new ImageIcon("egg.jpg");
            A=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name:");              ImageIcon hansel = new ImageIcon("hansel.jpg");

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sir/Ma`am \n "+A+"\n Welcome\n to Mang Inasal\n Please Choose The\n product you want to buy","Welcome" ,JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,welcome);
    while(x==1) 
            {
            c=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("  Categories" + "\n" +"[1] Drinks" + "\n" + "[2] Foods"));



    if(c==1)
        {choice=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("DRINKS" +"\n"
                        + "[1] Lemonade" + "\n"
                        + "[2] Coca Cola" + "\n"
                        + "[3] Sprite" + "\n"
                        + "[4] Mountain Dew" + "\n"
                        + "[5] Pepsi" + "\n"
                        + "[6] Cofee" +"\n"
                        + "[7] Hot Choco" +  "\n"
                        + "[8] Nestie Iced Tea" +"\n"
                        + "[9] Exit" +"\n"
                        + "Enter Your Choice:"));
    if(c==2)
        food=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Food" +"\n"
                        + "[1] L" + "\n"
                        + "[2] Coca Cola" + "\n"
                        + "[3] Sprite" + "\n"
                        + "[4] Mountain Dew" + "\n"
                        + "[5] Pepsi" + "\n"
                        + "[6] Cofee" +"\n"
                        + "[7] Hot Choco" +  "\n"
                        + "[8] Nestie Iced Tea" +"\n"
                        + "[9] Exit" +"\n"
                        + "Enter Your Choice:"));   

    }

        switch(choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    price = 20;
                    bibilhin= " Lemonade";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    price = 20;
                    bibilhin= "Coca Cola ";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    price =820;
                    bibilhin = "Sprite";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    price =205;
                    bibilhin= "Mountain dew";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    price =20;
                    bibilhin= "Pepsi";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    price =25;
                    bibilhin= "Cofee ";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    price =25;
                    bibilhin= "Hot Choco";
                    break;
                case 8:
                    price = 20;
                    bibilhin= "Nestie Ice tea";
                    break;
                case 9:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,transaction+"Total sales: " + gtotal,"Transactions",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You are about to exit!","Exit",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    do{
                        con=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Are you sure you want to exit?\n[1] Yes\n[0] No"));
                        if(con==1)
                            System.exit(0);
                        else if(con==1)
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"THANK YOU!\nGood Bye!","Exit",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                            break;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Choice!","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                            con=1;
                        }

                       }while(con==1);
                       continue;
                default:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Choice!","ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}

            do{//do1

            qty = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Quantity:"));

            if (qty>0)
                break;
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Input!","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                continue;
            }
            }while(q==1);//end do1

            total = price * qty;
            ptotal = ptotal+total;
            order = order +bibilhin+"                 "+qty+"                  "+price+"="+total+"\n";

            do  {//do2
            con = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Continue?[1] yes [0] no"));
                    if(con==1)
                    {

                        break;
                    }
                    else if(con==0)
                    {

                        do{
pay = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(order+"Total " +ptotal+"\nEnter Payment:"));
if(pay>=ptotal)
                                {

change = pay-ptotal;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"  \t                    Mang Inasal"+
            "\n\t           14 T molina st purok 6-B "+
            "\n\t              Alabang Muntinlupa City  "+
            "\nOperator: Micko Mendoza"+
            "\n\t----------------------------------------------------------------"+
            "\n\n\t   "+order+"\nTotal "+ptotal+
"\nCash "+pay+
"\nChange "+change+
            "\n----------------------------------------------------------------"+
            "\n\n \t            Thanks For buying!!!!!"+
                            "\n\t  This Serve as an official reciept DTSN:41D983"+
            "\n     \t       For Delivery Dial (519-6936)"+
            "\n    \t               Feedbacks"+
            "\n  \t             micko.mendoza@yahoo.com"
);
                                    y=0;
                                    z=0;
                                    x=1;
                                    gtotal = gtotal+ptotal;
                                    trans++;
                                    order="";
                                    transaction = transaction+"Transaction "+ trans+ " "+ptotal+"\n";//No of transactions
                                    ptotal = 0;
                                    do{
                                        con=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Next Customer?\n[1] Yes\n[0] No"));
                                        if(con==1)
                                            break;
                                        else if(con==0)
                                        {
                                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,transaction+"Total sales: " + gtotal,"Transactions",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                                            System.exit(0);
                                        }
                    else
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Choice!","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        continue;
                    }

                }while(con==1);
                                    break;
                                }
                            else
                                {
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Kulang pera mo");

                                    continue;
                                }
                            }while(z==1);//do3

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Intiger lang pwede","Continue",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        y=1;
                        continue;
                    }
                }   while(y==1);//do2

            //    break;




        switch(food)
            {
                case 11:
                    price = 20;
                    bibilhin= " Lemonade";
                    break;
                case 12:
                    price = 20;
                    bibilhin= "Coca Cola ";
                    break;
                case 13:
                    price =820;
                    bibilhin = "Sprite";
                    break;
                case 14:
                    price =205;
                    bibilhin= "Mountain dew";
                    break;
                case 15:
                    price =20;
                    bibilhin= "Pepsi";
                    break;
                case 16:
                    price =25;
                    bibilhin= "Cofee ";
                    break;
                case 17:
                    price =25;
                    bibilhin= "Hot Choco";
                    break;
                case 18:
                    price = 20;
                    bibilhin= "Nestie Ice tea";
                    break;
                case 19:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,transaction+"Total sales: " + gtotal,"Transactions",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You are about to exit!","Exit",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    do{
                        con=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Are you sure you want to exit?\n[1] Yes\n[0] No"));
                        if(con==1)
                            System.exit(0);
                        else if(con==1)
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"THANK YOU!\nGood Bye!","Exit",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                            break;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Choice!","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                            con=1;
                        }

                       }while(con==1);
                       continue;
                default:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Choice!","ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}

            do{//do1

            qty = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Quantity:"));

            if (qty>0)
                break;
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Input!","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                continue;
            }
            }while(q==1);//end do1

            total = price * qty;
            ptotal = ptotal+total;
            order = order +bibilhin+"                 "+qty+"                  "+price+"="+total+"\n";

            do  {//do2
            con = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Continue?[1] yes [0] no"));
                    if(con==1)
                    {

                        break;
                    }
                    else if(con==0)
                    {

                        do{
pay = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(order+"Total " +ptotal+"\nEnter Payment:"));
if(pay>=ptotal)
                                {

change = pay-ptotal;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"  \t                    Mang Inasal"+
                "\n\t           14 T molina st purok 6-B "+
            "\n\t              Alabang Muntinlupa City  "+
            "\nOperator: Micko Mendoza"+
            "\n\t----------------------------------------------------------------"+
            "\n\n\t   "+order+"\nTotal "+ptotal+
"\nCash "+pay+
"\nChange "+change+
            "\n----------------------------------------------------------------"+
            "\n\n \t            Thanks For buying!!!!!"+
                            "\n\t  This Serve as an official reciept DTSN:41D983"+
            "\n     \t       For Delivery Dial (519-6936)"+
            "\n    \t               Feedbacks"+
            "\n  \t             micko.mendoza@yahoo.com"
    );
                                    y=0;
                                    z=0;
                                    x=1;
                                    gtotal = gtotal+ptotal;
                                    trans++;
                                    order="";
                                    transaction = transaction+"Transaction "+ trans+ " "+ptotal+"\n";//No of transactions
                                    ptotal = 0;
                                    do{
                                        con=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Next Customer?\n[1] Yes\n[0] No"));
                                        if(con==1)
                                            break;
                                        else if(con==0)
                                        {
                                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,transaction+"Total sales: " + gtotal,"Transactions",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                                            System.exit(0);
                                        }
                    else
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Choice!","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        continue;
                    }

                }while(con==1);
                                    break;
                                }
                            else
                                {
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Kulang pera mo");

                                    continue;
                                }
                            }while(z==1);//do3

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Intiger lang pwede","Continue",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        y=1;
                        continue;
                    }
                }   while(y==1);//do2




                continue;



}   
}
}
```